Could not load SWT library. Reasons: Не найдена указанная процедура
Скачал STS, распаковал в C:, пробую запустить и получаю ошибку.
Лог:
   
    !SESSION 2024-09-21 17:15:34.699 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.25.0.202409101855
java.version=21.0.4
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=ru_RU
Framework arguments:  -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4

!ENTRY ch.qos.logback.classic 1 0 2024-09-21 17:15:37.890
!MESSAGE Activated before the state location was initialized. Retry after the state location is initialized.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2024-09-21 17:15:38.920
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    C:\STS\spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.25.0.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\419\0\.cp\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура
    no swt-win32 in java.library.path: C:\STS\spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.25.0.RELEASE;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/STS/spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64/sts-4.25.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin/server;C:/STS/spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64/sts-4.25.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Java\jdk-21\bin;C:\STS\spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.25.0.RELEASE;;.
    no swt in java.library.path: C:\STS\spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.25.0.RELEASE;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/STS/spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64/sts-4.25.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin/server;C:/STS/spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64/sts-4.25.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.4.v20240802-1551/jre/bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Java\jdk-21\bin;C:\STS\spring-tool-suite-4-4.25.0.RELEASE-e4.33.0-win32.win32.x86_64\sts-4.25.0.RELEASE;;.
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Пользователь\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Пользователь\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\Пользователь\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll
    C:\Users\Пользователь\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4966r5.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура

    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.STARTUPINFO.<clinit>(STARTUPINFO.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:271)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1481)

